# Regex DataAnnotation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, data-annotations

I can't figure out why this regular expression doesn't work the way I want it to. I want it to allow something like this: "Test123#%&*- Test"

```
[RegularExpression("[^a-zA-Z0-9/#%&*\\- ]")]
```

The MSDN documentation only gives one example...

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
```

I don't want to limit input to any specific character length, which the MSDN example does do. I have used this regex pattern with the `Regex` object in .net and it works just fine. Why would the `DataAnnotations` work differently?

Comment: DataAnnotations as much as I'm aware of don't work with WPF.

Comment: It does work. See this [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/26/wpf-data-validation-using-net-data-annotations.aspx) for an explanation.

Comment: The MSDN example has the carrot (^) outside of the square brackets while your example has it inside. I suggest moving or removing it as you *want* the regex to match with your valid value. But, I've seen other forums that indicate DA and WPF do not work (never tried it myself, though).

Comment: You are correct about moving the `^` outside. However it will only validate a single character unless include the `{1,40}$` notation at the end. I don't want to limit the field to any particular length though.

Comment: @Geo242 - Then I'd just remove the carrot all together. It will then validate each individual character you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way of using a negated class to find not allowed characters is wrong. I can't find a documentation to prove it, but it seems logical to me.

I think you need to give a pattern that matches the allowed input.

Try

```
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9/#%&*\\- ]*$")]
```

The `*` quantifier makes it repeat the character class 0 or more times. This allows also the empty string! If you don't want the empty string use the quantifier `+`, that would be one or more.

`*` is a shortcut for `{0,}`. if you omit the second number it means there is no maximum match

`+` is a shortcut for `{1,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex DataAnnotations is written in a way to find what is valid, rather than finding what is invalid. You WANT to match with valid values.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx)

I'd drop your carrot (^). This will allow each individual character you supply to be validated. If anything fails, you'll generate your error message.